# Pass values to TimePickerFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I have a working TimePickerFragment which uses the current time as the default values for the picker. 
Now I want to pass the old selected value for minute and hour to show in the picker. How can I do that?

This is the code:

Activity:

```
    TimePickerFragment newFragmentNight = TimePickerFragment.newInstance(TO_TIME_PICKER_ID);    
    newFragmentNight.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
```

DialogFragment:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
{

private int mId;
private TimePickedListener mListener;

static TimePickerFragment newInstance(int id) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("picker_id", id);
    TimePickerFragment fragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
// here I don't want to use the current time, I want to use the time passing from the activity
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

mId = getArguments().getInt("picker_id");


// create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just adding new values to the `newInstance()` static method and bundle it that way.  It can pass on the information just the same as you would with a constructor.  Try the following:

```
static TimePickerFragment newInstance(int id, int hour, int minute) 
{
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("picker_id", id);
    args.putInt("hour", hour);
    args.putInt("minute", minute);
    TimePickerFragment fragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Bundle args = getArguments();

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    //The second input is a default value in case hour or minute are empty
    int hour = args.getInt("hour", c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    int minute = args.getInt("minute", c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

    mId = getArguments().getInt("picker_id");


    // create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, 
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
```

Hope this helps.  Good luck!